# Read Google Sheet from Google Slides getting permission error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, google-slides

```
                        NEW INFORMATION
```

Nov 17, 2020 - I can run onOpen from the script without getting the permission error.  I can run the function that displays data from the script or the menu (after I have run onOpen from the script). I don't think there were any changes to the code but here it is again.  The manifest is definitely unchanged.

```
//@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
function globalVariables(){ 
  var variables = {
                   // this is the Connect Four Game
                   sheetId: '1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA',   
                   sheetUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA/edit?usp=sharing'
                  };
  return variables; //return a dictionary of keys and values
}

function onOpen() {
  Logger.log("In onOpen" );
  var variables = globalVariables();   //load the Global variables 
  Logger.log("In onOpen sheetUrl from globalVariables: " + variables.sheetUrl );
  try  {
  
//      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(variables.sheetUrl);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetId)
    if (!ss) {
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert("Spreadsheet not found!");
      return;
    }  
  }    catch(e)    {
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert(e);
      return;
  }

  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu( 'Ask ?')
      .addItem('BE1','BE1')
      .addItem('BE2','BE2')
      .addItem('BE3','BE3')
      .addItem('BE4','BE4')
      .addToUi(); 
   
  prepareQuestions(ss);
  Logger.log("After prepareQuestions");
  setupSheets(ss);  // only want to do this once
  Logger.log("After setupSheets");
}

function setupSheets(ss) {

SlidesApp.getUi().alert("setupSheets() triggered");

  var nextI = '1'; 
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  cache.put('nextI', nextI);
console.log("1. cache.put('nextI') = " + nextI);
SlidesApp.getUi().alert("End onOpne) = ");
}

function BE1() {
SlidesApp.getUi().alert("BE1() triggered");
  var variables = globalVariables();   //load the Global variables 
  var sheetName = 'BE1';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetId).getSheetByName('BE1');
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet BE1 not found");
    SlidesApp.getUi().alert("Sheet BE1 not found");
    return;
  } 
  getNextQ(sheet);
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert("end BE1 function");
}
```

---

I am the creator of both the spreadsheet and the slides. They are in the same folder on My Drive.

I have added Oauth to the manifest in the Slide:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
  ]
}
```

I have tried to open the Spreadsheet by ID and URL. The error is:

Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I have tried creating a trigger (I have no idea what this is for) but when creating it the only options were time based which does not seem useful. The presence of the trigger does not change the error.

[image: view existing trigger edit]

The code bound to the Slide

```
//@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
function globalVariables(){ 
  var variables = {
                   // this is the Connect Four Game
                   sheetId: '1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA',   
                   sheetUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA/edit?usp=sharing'
                  };
  return variables; //return a dictionary of keys and values
}

//function installableOpen()    {   // never starts
function onOpen() {
  var variables = globalVariables();   //load the Global variables 
  try  {
  
//      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(variables.sheetUrl);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetId)
    if (!ss) {
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert("Spreadsheet not found!");
      return;
    }  
  }    catch(e)    {
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert(e);
      return;
  }
 etc...
```

I added "//@NotOnlyCurrentDoc" as this was recommended in some places.

Share status of spreadsheet
[image]

The purpose of accessing the spreadsheet is to get data to display in html with showModalDialog. I have wandered through information on custom menus, dialogs, and sidebars to Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms, custom functions and macros, web apps, add-ons but I don't understand any of these. I was hoping to keep this simple. Custom function says it cannot display html (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) so that would be useless.

Any ideas appreciated.

As result of comment I changed the manifest as follows but the error is unchanged.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
I received this sort of email after deleting the triggers

[image]

Comment: The error is different. You can't use time triggers to call `ui` elements. Delete  time trigger. The "Event source" should be "From slides"

Comment: all triggers have been deleted. Thanks. Still getting error when opening spreadsheet (onOpen runs I guess) but do not get permission error if I run onOpen from script editor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRAZY FIX - I connected to the slide to which the script was bound before connecting to the spreadsheet! Pure chance discovery but the permission error is gone.

```
function onOpen() {

  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var presLen = slides.length;
  Logger.log("num slides: " + presLen );

  var variables = globalVariables();   //load the Global variables 
  if (!variables.sheetId)  {
    Logger.log("SheetId not retrieved from global variables!");
    return;
  }    
  
  try  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetId);
    if (!ss)  {
      Logger.log("The data spreadsheet does not exist");
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert("The data spreadsheet does not exist"  + variables.sheetId );
      return;
    }
  }  catch (e)  {
    Logger.log("    in catch for openBYId: "  + variables.sheetId );
    SlidesApp.getUi().alert(e);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

For the method

`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`

**you are required to provide the scope**

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

instead of

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`

If you do not want to provide this scope, consider binding your script to the spreadsheet and use the method

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`

which accepts the scope

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`

Comment: After changing what? The scopes in the manifest or after changing `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`? Do you get the problem only on simple trigger (`onOpen`)? This is an authorization problem because you are not allowed to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` on simple trigger. Use [installable onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead

Comment: Then this should work if you run the code without simple triggers.

Comment: I deleted the trigger. Closed and reopened the slides set / presentation and got the same error.

Comment: Did find a bunch of these emails about triggers from my attempts. I added the image to the original above.

Comment: The email about trigger failure is dated from the 15th of November. When you say you deleted the trigger - do you mean that you renamed the `onOpen`function to something different?